# can not start angular hello-world project - An unhandled exception occurred

Tags: node.js, npm, angular-cli

I can not start angular hello-world project on windows 10.
I installed the latest node.js and I run the following commands:

```
npm install -g @angular/cli  
ng new hello-world
cd hello-world
ng serve
```

I got the following error messages:

> An unhandled exception occurred: Unknown browser query `basedir=$(dirname "$(echo "$0" | sed -e 's`. Maybe you are using old Browserslist or made typo in query.
>   See "C:\Users{USER}\AppData\Local\Temp\ng-dlwIKN\angular-errors.log" for further details.